# Gerrit open id sign in issue

Tags: openid, gerrit

I have recently installed Gerrit on my server, and I've linked it to a mysql database. ALl good, so far, I've registered using Open id, the new account has been successfully inserted into database and all good.
But today, I've connected my computer to another network, and when I signed in, I had no rights to read, or write to my projects (as should), because now, gerrit created another entry, identical to my last one, but with different external_id.

What can I do? I don't want to remove my old account or to have a new one each time I log in...

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume when you switched to another network, the URL for your Gerrit server changed.  This caused the OpenId account credentials to be different - this is a security feature built in to many/most OpenId providers.  You can merge the two accounts together by editing the database by hand (and do this for all other users after they log in), or switch the URL for your Gerrit server back to the original URL.  I'm not aware of any other solutions.